# Write to Realm in a loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

I am storing workout information in Realm from this object class:

```
class Workout: Object {

    @objc dynamic var date: Date?
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var exercise: String?
    @objc dynamic var sets = 0
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
    @objc dynamic var kg: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var notes: String?
}
```

I have data stored as an array, that I want to write to Realm, like this:

```
var workoutName = ""
var exercises = [String]()
var sets = [Int]()
var reps = [Int]()
var kg = [Double]()
var notes = [String]()

@IBAction func saveWorkoutButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)

    let currenDate = Date() // Get the current date

    let myWorkout = Workout()
    myWorkout.date = currenDate
    myWorkout.name = workoutName

    for i in 0 ..< exercises.count {
        myWorkout.exercise = exercises[i]
        myWorkout.sets = sets[i]
        myWorkout.reps = reps[i]
        myWorkout.kg = kg[i]
        myWorkout.notes = notes[i]

        realm.add(myWorkout)
    }

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(myWorkout)
    }
}
```

The problem in this case is that when running the `realm.write ...` it only adds the last value from the `for i in 0` function. I tried putting the `realm.write` function inside of the `for i in 0` loop, but then it crashes. Each of the arrays contains equal numbers of objects. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have 5 parallel arrays all containing fragments of the same data? That's incredibly error prone. You'll eventually make a mistake that makes the arrays out of sync, such as forgetting to add a `kg` value

Comment: @Alexander If any of the values is empty, it wont even save it, so no worries.

Comment: That's not enough to protect you from the many kinds of inevitable bugs that can happen with this design. For example, what if you add to `sets`, `reps`, `kg` and `notes`, but forget to add to `exercises`? You would have an incomplete data set, and it'll silently fail. You should make your `workout` objects right at the place where you collect this data.

Comment: @Alexander Well, do you have any tips for me, in stead of just criticising the way I choose to do it?

Comment: Well you've already identified the problem with parallel arrays, since you're converting them into coherent objects (of type `Workout`). You just need to do this process earlier, to create `Workout` objects right from the beginning, completely removing this "all the data is split up in many parallel array" part.

Comment: This is a simple issue. You've created one object with `let myWorkout = Workout()` (which will create a unique Realm object) and then you are updating it's values over and over within the loop, never creating a new object. Just move that `let` statement (and the two following statements) inside the loop so new objects are created with each iteration. Keeping in mind that each object will have a slightly different timestamp but they will all have the same workout name. You can also move the try block inside the loop and remove the realm.add that's there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
var myWorkouts:[Workout] = []
for i in 0 ..< exercises.count {
    let myWorkout = Workout()
    myWorkout.date = currenDate
    myWorkout.name = workoutName
    myWorkout.exercise = exercises[i]
    myWorkout.sets = sets[i]
    myWorkout.reps = reps[i]
    myWorkout.kg = kg[i]
    myWorkout.notes = notes[i]
    myWorkouts.append(myWorkout)
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(myWorkouts)
}
```

You should only `add` and `write` once if possible for performance optimisation.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Should I do `try! realm.write { ` or should I also add some error handling if any error? In that case, how?

Comment: @qtngo Good first start, but I suggest avoiding ever writing `for i in 0..<a.count`. It's too easily to accidentally write `for i in 0...a.count`, leading to a bug. Plus, that doesn't even work for array slices. Instead, use `for i in a.indices`

Comment: @Trinity: in Realm documentation, they always use try!. So I think that's the good way to go. From my experience using Realm, I don't have any problem with that. Furthermore, if app suddenly have problem writing into the disk for some reason, it may be better for explicitly crash then continuing with a bug.